# Delimiting and selecting string in SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, dbeaver

I would like to Delimit my data on and underscore and select a the 3rd column.

Example Input:

```
**Name**
Car_2019_NYC_Accident_News
Truck_19_LA_Rental
Pad_Run_Detroit_Monkey_18
```

Desired Output:

```
**Market**
NYC
LA
Detroit
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have a look here https://coderwall.com/p/zzgo-w/splitting-strings-with-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`split_part()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/SPLIT_PART.html):

```
select split_part(name, '_', 3) as market
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c9766c37bda44fe80fae49bde7e59550) is a db<>fiddle